# Subscribe between fields In sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table with these fields

```
id,cid,cv
```

with these data

```
1,5,code
2,3,code4
3,3,cod2
1,4,code5
1,3,code4
```

] want select id what cid=5 and cv=code and cid=3 or 4 and cv=code4.
I expect that id=1.
I used this query,but result is 0

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE (cid='5' and cv='code') and (cid in ('3','4') and cv='code4')
```

sorry for bad english.

Comment: In your example, cv has to be = 'code' and cv has to be equal to 'code4' - it can't be both for any one record.  Do you not want "1,3,code4" to come up in your results?  That matches the second part of your AND.  But no record will ever be both code and code4, right?

Comment: i want 1,5,code and 1,3,code4 that subscribe is 1.for example user post me this data (5=>code),(3=>code4,4=>code4) for search.i serach in table and post to user ID that cid=5 and cv=code and cid in(3,4) and cv=code4.

Comment: @MJH: But what you describe should lead to result 1 and 2 and not only 1.

Comment: Suppose id is product,cid is property's category ,and cv is property's value.u want select product with property's value 'code' in category 5,with value 'code4' in categories 3or4

Comment: try this and select laptop with company 'dell' and ram=2 or cpu=2 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40054/4

Comment: @MJH - I think I see.  This is called "key value pair" I think, retagging might get more answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id FROM my_table  
WHERE (cid=5 and cv='code') 
or ((cid = 3 and cv='code4') 
and (cid = 4 and cv='code4')) 
group by id
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45dac/12)

Comment: no,if i use OR, result contain id=2.i want only id=1 (for this example)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (change the AND between the parenteses to OR):

```
SELECT id 
FROM table 
WHERE (cid='5' and cv='code') OR (cid in ('3','4') and cv='code4')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `ORs` instead of `ANDs`

```
SELECT id 
FROM table 
WHERE (cid='5' and cv='code') 
    OR (cid in ('3','4') and cv='code4')
```

Answer (score 1):

I put this at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40054/51  (you can tell by the last number being 51 I took some wrong turns).  I think this is called "Key Value," I proposed an edit to the tags for this post, but I think you should re-tag it to include key-value.  Anyway: databases like this are difficult to query compared to approaches where one row refers to one thing - instead you have one row referring to one attribute.  So if you want to know something about what "things" have certain attributes, you have to paste the attributes for each thing together in one row.  Run the query below and you'll see what I mean:

```
SELECT  laptops.laptop, rams.termvalue as ramCount,
  cpus.termvalue as cpusCount, 
  maker.termvalue as company
  FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT laptop FROM my_table) As Laptops

LEFT JOIN (SELECT laptop, termvalue FROM my_table 
            WHERE term = 'ram') AS rams
            ON rams.laptop = laptops.laptop
LEFT JOIN (SELECT laptop, termvalue FROM my_table 
            WHERE term = 'cpu') AS cpus
            ON cpus.laptop = laptops.laptop
LEFT JOIN (SELECT laptop, termvalue FROM my_table 
            WHERE term = 'company') AS maker
            ON maker.laptop = laptops.laptop
```

If you put up other questions about this type of database, you should always mention that you're using a "key/value" arrangement, it's uncommon and not what any of us assumed.

In your fiddler example you wanted to find company = dell and cpu = 2 or ram = 2, so you would query ***that*** whole query by wrapping it in parentheses and giving it an alias, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  (
SELECT  laptops.laptop, rams.termvalue as ramCount,
  cpus.termvalue as cpusCount, 
  maker.termvalue as company
  FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT laptop FROM my_table) As Laptops

LEFT JOIN (SELECT laptop, termvalue FROM my_table 
            WHERE term = 'ram') AS rams
            ON rams.laptop = laptops.laptop
LEFT JOIN (SELECT laptop, termvalue FROM my_table 
            WHERE term = 'cpu') AS cpus
            ON cpus.laptop = laptops.laptop
LEFT JOIN (SELECT laptop, termvalue FROM my_table 
            WHERE term = 'company') AS maker
            ON maker.laptop = laptops.laptop
) as laps
WHERE  company = 'dell' AND (cpuscount = 2 OR ramcount = 2)
```